# ScrollView and Canvas in QML

Tags: qt, canvas, scrollview, qml

Good day!
I'm trying to display multiple charts in different tabs, using `Canvas`. The scale of the graphs will be somewhat greater than the actual size of the display, so I want to use `ScrollView`. Have this code in several files:

**main.qml**:

```
TabView {
    id: tabView
    Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignCenter
    Layout.fillWidth: true
    Layout.fillHeight: true

    Tab1 {
        id: tab1
    }

    //...
}
```

**Tab1.qml**:

```
Tab {
    active: true

    function init()
    {
        item.plot.requestPaint()
    }

    ScrollView {
        property var plot: _plot
        Plot {
            width: 3000
            id: _plot
        }
    }
}
```

**Plot.qml**:

```
Canvas {
    function draw()
    {
        console.log("draw go")
        var ctx = getContext("2d")
        ctx.reset()

        //...
    }

    onPaint: {
        draw()
    }
}
```

At some point, the function `init()` is called.

The problem is that when using `ScrollView` signal `Paint` is not called. Without `ScrollView` everything works well. Errors in the console does not arise.

**Qt 5.4.1**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give your `Canvas` a height:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2

Window {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 300
    height: 300

    ScrollView {
        anchors.fill: parent

        Canvas {
            width: 3000
            height: window.height
            onPaint: {
                console.log("draw go")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is a little confusing to me, since the [documentation says](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-scrollview.html#details):

> Only one Item can be a direct child of the ScrollView and the child is implicitly anchored to fill the scroll view.

But then it goes on to say:

> The width and height of the child item will be used to define the size of the content area.

Which seem like contradictory statements.